# How to do styling in templates as my styling not working in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i downloaded code from github and ran its server it showed me output with styled templates like this:

[image]

But after two days, my styling gone wrong, similarly in my own project where I was working styling was working but now, it gives me view like this:

[image]

and forms displaying like this:

[image]

I don't know why it gone like this as two days before it was working fine, and also github project that i have downloaded, its styling also not working, even i didn't make any change in that downloaded project. First it was working. Now in both downloaded and my own express travel project as I was following that downloaded project templates these templates are not working fine.

Is there any error of static files? or CSS styling? how can i resolve this?

here are my template code:

add_manager_template.html

```html
{% extends 'admin_template/base_template.html' %}
{% block page_title %}
Add Manager
{% endblock page_title %}
{% block main_content %}
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- general form elements -->
            <div class="card card-primary">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Add Manager</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card-header -->
              <!-- form start -->
                {% url 'add_manager_save' as action_path %}
                {% include 'admin_template/form_template.html' with messages=messages form=form action_path=action_path button_text="Add Manager" %}
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->



          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
{% endblock main_content %}
```

form_template.html

```html
 <form role="form" action="{{ action_path }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="card-body">

                    {% for field in form %}
                  <div class="form-group">
                      {{ field.errors }}
                      {{ field.label_tag }}
                      {{ field }}
                  </div>
                    {% endfor %}

                   <div class="form-group">
                      {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                        {% if message.tags == 'error' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if message.tags == 'success' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:10px">{{ message }}</div>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->

                <div class="card-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{ button_text }}</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

home_content.html

```html
{% extends 'admin_template/base_template.html' %}
{% block page_title %}
Home
{% endblock page_title %}
{% block main_content %}
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
{% endblock main_content %}
```

sidebar_template.html

```html
{% load static %}
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="#" class="brand-link">
      <img src="{% static 'dist/img/logo.jpg' %}" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">Express Travels</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="{% static 'dist/img/admin.png' %}" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">{{ user.username }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item">
            {% url 'add_manager' as add_manager %}
            <a href="{% url 'admin_home' %}" class="nav-link {% if request.path == add_manager %} active {% endif %}">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
              <p>
                Home
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            {% url 'add_manager' as add_manager %}
            <a href="{{ add_manager }}" class="nav-link {% if request.path == add_manager %} active {% endif %}">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
              <p>
                Add Manager
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            {% url 'edit_manager' as edit_manager %}
          <a href="#" class="nav-link {% if request.path == edit_manager %} active {% endif %}">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
            <p>
              Edit Manager
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>
          
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

base_template.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Express Travels</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css' %}">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Tempusdominus Bbootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css' %}">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css' %}">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dist/css/adminlte.min.css' %}">
  <!-- overlayScrollbars -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css' %}">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' %}">
  <!-- summernote -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css' %}">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block custom_css %}{% endblock custom_css %}
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h4 style="margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 5px;">Express Travels | Admin Panel</h4>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Messages Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="logout_user">
          Logout
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right navbar links -->
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    {% include 'admin_template/sidebar_template.html' with user=user id=id %}

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
   <div class="content-wrapper">
       <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">
                {% block page_title %}
                {% endblock page_title %}
            </h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home Page</a></li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->
     {% block main_content %}{% endblock main_content %}

  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->


</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- ChartJS -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js' %}"></script>
<!-- JQVMap -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js' %}"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/moment/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Tempusdominus Bootstrap 4 -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Summernote -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- overlayScrollbars -->
<script src="{% static 'plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="{% static 'dist/js/adminlte.js' %}"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<<!--  script src="{% static 'dist/js/pages/dashboard.js' %}"></script>  -->
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<!-- <script src="{% static 'dist/js/demo.js' %}"></script> -->

{% block custom_js %}
{% endblock custom_js %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add code as text, not as images of your code

Comment: I edited and provided the html code.

Comment: press ctrl+shift+R to fully refresh your browser. This will remove alll the old css catches which might solve your problem cause it doesnt look like the issue of your code.

Comment: yes I tried it, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i just putted this project to new virtual environment and executed,now it worked for me.